# How to identify unused columns/calculated columns present in the report (IronPython perhaps?)?

Tags: python, ironpython, spotfire

We speak of a large report with many pages and visualisations on it.
The only quite obvious idea I have is to open each page and review all the visualisations and text areas
manually but I wonder if there can be a script that would help with the task.

Comment: Hi Jacek- I attempted something like this a while back, but found it to be pretty complicated if there are a lot of different visual types in the report. I used the wiki post below as a starting point

https://community.tibco.com/wiki/find-all-columns-and-expressions-used-graphs-tables-or-visuals-spotfire

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get some of this information out of the Spotfire database.  I'm still on version 10.3, not the newer version, but I know that they are tracking more and more user actions in later versions.

Comment: Its not about user actions. Its about loading from ILs the columns that are not used by any visualisations. Also unused calculated columns are the concern here.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to script this.  It would be really helpful if there were.